# How to set error border to RelativeLayout? EditText box is placed in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, border, android-relativelayout

[image]

The above image shows that only the edit text box's border changes to red. I need the relative layout to change it's border to red when the edit text field is empty on button click. The  "white" portion on the screen is `RelativeLayout`.

Main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.phone );

        final EditText number = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.mobilenumber );
        final String msisdn=number.getText().toString();
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(msisdn)) {
                    number.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_error_background);

                    number.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.like_selected, 0);
                    return;
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Post some code what you have tried.

Comment: So you need to write your own method to observe the edit text field is empty and set the layout red.Don't forget about the else case :P

Comment: where is your code to set a color for relative layout?

Comment: You need change background when error occur

Comment: @sree that is what Iam asking. whats the code to change the border color of relative layout  when  the button is clicked  when theedit box is empty

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari how? can u please share the code

Comment: why don't you search on google?

Comment: @Sree I didnt find any..

Comment: replace your edittext with the layout it may work.

Comment: @ShriyaD.S you need two image or drawbales whom  you can change according to you need while error occur or not. Basically set Edittext background

Comment: @ShriyaD.S  i have answered as per your request. I hope its work for you

Answer (score 1):

You change your editText background color as follows.

```
button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(msisdn)) {
                number.setBackground(R.drawable.your_error_background);


            }
            else{
                 number.setBackground(R.drawable.your_normal_bakground);
            }
        }
    });
```

Use `setBackground()` method instead of `setBackgroundResource()` method because its by default accept drawable resource

I hope its work for you. Thank You